# CosmosDB Distinct query - slow performance

Tags: performance, query-optimization, azure-cosmosdb

We are using CosmosDB and I'm running a Distinct query as follows

```
Select Distinct c.SomeType, c.SomeName
From c
Where c.ptkey = 'WHATEVERPTKEY'
And c.SomeCategory = 'WhateverCategory'
```

...where ptkey is the field that holds the partition key.  The above works but takes around 1-1.5 minutes to complete (I'm assuming because some/many of the documents are very large) - I've tried filtering on the partition's unique key (id), using a "Group By", and played with "Order By" (restrictions apply when you combine the two and/or only one field is allowed in the Order By unless you have a composite key), but not much changes.

The one thing that does make a big difference is creating an Indexing Policy as follows

```
"compositeIndexes": [
    [
        {
            "path": "/ptkey"
        },
        {
            "path": "/SomeCategory"
        },
        {
            "path": "/SomeType"
        },
        {
            "path": "/SomeName"
        }
    ]
]
```

...however, my question is how do I limit this composite key definition to only apply to the specific partition key the above query is for ('WHATEVERPTKEY' - as we have around a dozen partition keys within our database/collection) and secondly is there any alternative/better option (other than re-modelling our data)

Note my Query Stats when running the query in Azure CosmosDB Data Explorer ***without*** an index are as follows

```
Query Statistics
746.96 RUs
1 - 12
Retrieved document count 0
Retrieved document size 0 bytes
Output document count 0
Output document size 1789 bytes
Index hit document count 0
Index lookup time 1.1900000000000002 ms
Document load time 366.48990000000003 ms
Query engine execution time 29.0101 ms
System function execution time 0.76 ms
User defined function execution time 0 ms
Document write time 0.02 ms
1
```

UPDATE

- full indexing policy of the collection is below

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ],
    "compositeIndexes": [
        [
            {
                "path": "/ptkey",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/SomeCategory",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/SomeType",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/SomeName",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: A composite index would have no impact on this query. Can you include the complete index policy for this container? You are definitely not using the index based upon the index hit count.

Comment: @MarkBrown - I've updated the post with the indexing policy - the query I'm running that looks to have an improved performance after the indexing policy is in place is as follows
SELECT uniq.ptkey,uniq.SomeCategory,uniq.SomeType,uniq.SomeName
FROM (
    SELECT c.ptkey,c.SomeCategory,c.SomeType,c.SomeName
    from c
    where c.ptkey = 'WHATEVERPTKEY'
    and c.SomeCategory='WhateverCategory'
    group by c.ptkey,c.SomeCategory,c.SomeType, c.SomeName
) as uniq

Comment: The above query brings about the following query stats: 7809.127 RUs, 1 - 80, Retrieved document count 21000, Retrieved document size 1893070755 bytes, Output document count 80, Output document size 7095 bytes, Index hit document count 30.01, Index lookup time 1.1400000000000001 ms, Document load time 3801.42 ms, Query engine execution time 316.4699 ms, System function execution time 0 ms, User defined function execution time 0 ms, Document write time 0.17 ms, 1

Answer (score 1):

So the query metrics in the portal can sometimes not show accurate data when there are LOTS of multiple pages of results but it does often work.

With DISTINCT the cost can depend on how many results you're dealing with. If you're expecting just a few results the impact on cost is low. If you're into thousands, it can get very expensive. Work is happening to make that less expensive. It's a ways out before it will be released.

Can you try again with just this as your index policy?

```
{
"indexingMode": "consistent",
"automatic": true,
"includedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/*"
    }
],
"excludedPaths": [
    {
        "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
    }
],
"compositeIndexes": [
    [
        {
            "path": "/ptkey",
            "order": "ascending"
        },
        {
            "path": "/SomeCategory",
            "order": "ascending"
        }
    ]
]
```

}

Comment: Will give it a try - also the original question was about how do you isolate  a specific indexing policy to a single partition key - do you know how this is done ?

Comment: That's not possible. Not sure why you'd do that either as it is kind of at odds with having a collection that can scale. If you have different entities in a container that are unique to a partition key value just define the index for them. You'll notice much difference given you're only talking about 20GB of data. Plus, given it's per PK, as long as you specify the PK in the WHERE the performance will be fine.